# System of differential equations with a "jump"

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a system

$$X_1'(\tau)+p (e^{X_2(\tau)-X_1(\tau)}-1)=v_1$$

$$X_2'(\tau)+q (e^{X_1(\tau)-X_2(\tau)}-1)=v_2$$

First, how can I solve this system and obtain $X_i(\tau)$?

Second, consider a two state continuous time Markov chain with transition probabilities $p$ and $q$. In the first state it takes a value $v_1$ and in the second the value $v_2$. Can we relate the solution to the properties of the Markov chain?

My intuition tells that $X_i(\tau)$ is related to $\mathbb{E}_{t,i}\int_{t}^{t+\tau}v(s)ds$, the expectation over the integral of values of the Markov-chain conditional on currently being in state $i$. One can see that this is true in the special case that the transition probabilities are zero $p=q=0$. But is this generally correct?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of $X'$; isn't $X$ a stochastic process with discontinuous paths? Or is this just a differential equation system that you're interested in how to solve and what it might mean for the underlying chain?

Comment: @Ian $X$ is not the value of the Markov chain. My hunch is that it is related to an integral of the values of the chain. But I am not sure and making an interpretation about $X$ is part of the question.

Comment: @Ian So your second interpretation is correct.

Comment: Check [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69038/jump-diffusion-process-question/69060?noredirect=1#comment100715_69060) answer which I think is similar to yours.